# Place variable into array in Python

Tags: python

My text file has a single line that will be overwritten from time to time. The actual value is:

> 5,7,1,1,6,7,27

I want to read this `*.txt` and place its content inside a `np.array`, so that it would be:

```
new = np.array([[5,7,1,1,6,7,27]])
```

What I tried:

```
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
txt = Path('c:\MyFolder\myValue.txt').read_text()
new = np.array([[txt]])
```

How to correct this?

Comment: what happens when you do it this way? Do you get an error message / traceback? I'd suggest `print(txt)` to see what this object actually is.

Comment: have you looked up "how to read a text file into a numpy array"?

Comment: @JacobIRR the message was **"ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 7 but received input with shape (None, 1)"**. Yes, i used `print(txt)` and it showed 5,7,1,1,6,7,27. When `print(new)` it showed [['5,7,1,1,6,7,27']]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Hi! Yes, thank you, but I did a thorough search but yielded unsatisfactory results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
All I did was split the string by the `','` delimiter, then cast the values to `int`.

```
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
txt = Path('c:\MyFolder\myValue.txt').read_text()
new = np.array([[int(i) for i in txt.split(',')]])
```